# viewForHeaderInSection on insertSections is called for visible section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello  i have a weird edge case on **UItableview** when a new section is inserted.

**What I expect:** I insert a new section at 0 and viewFor/willDisplayed is called for that newly inserted section only.

**What Im getting:** I get the desired behaviour in all cases were current section count is 2 > N. **But** if there is currently only one section in the table and i insert a new one. viewFor/willDisplayed will be called on both 0 and 1.

This severely messes up the ui animations as I on insert-completion, update the content of section 1 (without reloading it explicitly) and call beginUpdate/endUpdate to update its height. But in this edge case this will now be called after its already got its new model set without any animations though viewForHeader resulting in a glitchy animation.

Anyone have any insight on how to overcome this Feture/bug of uitableview?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are doing in `viewFor` and in `willDisplayed`.  I suspect that there is a better way to set the height.

Comment: im not doing anything out of the ordinary in those functions. only configuring section with data model in **forView** and caching height in **will display**. 
As far as im aware tableview will always get its height from heightForHeaderInSection regardless of a begin/end, insert or reload operation. **My problem is not height related**, but rather that **viewfor/display** is called on a section that is already visible. But only in this one senario where 1 section is on display and then never again.

Comment: What animations are you adding?

Comment: I have some fade in/out on text content change, as well as some more complex "morphing" of a spinner into a fail/pass state. But these are run in a transaction completion block. Eg they will run once insertsection has completed. So the whole problem comes when insertsection at 0 also reloads content of 1 for no reason as it's already displayed and visible. So once the block is triggered to update the section at 1  it's viewmodel was already changed in viewfor.

Comment: Can you share the animation code.